# How to get only city names from autocomplete using GoogleAPI for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I wish to get only city names from autocomplete api for iOS. For example if i search like Avadi then it should return city name as Chennai. I used google places api. It returns many strings separated by comma from which i couldn't get exact city name if user give any area name of city.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Avadi&types=(cities)&types=postal_code&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

Comment: Let me guess... Are you asking us to make code for you? If don't, please post YOUR code and tell us what is the problem and what have you tried.

Comment: Hi @bcesars Click this [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCPcQgVAd1WyiU5oI1NmYZAOBy8Ak8gL0Q&input=saidapet)

Comment: @bcesars - His question seems fine, he is asking if there is a web request that filters the results to city names only Or returns something that can be parsed for city names. More information would be helpful but his question certainly didn't deserve a down vote.